# "Flatten" the an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash

What is the best way to "flatten" JSON array of objects using pure JS or Lodash?

For example I have an array

```
[
  {
  "name": "Mat",
  "age": "18",
  "studies": [
      {
        "subject": "English",
         "mark": 5
      },
      {
        "subject": "Maths",
         "mark": 4
      }
    ],
  },
  {
  "name": "Alice",
  "age": 20,
  "city": "New York"
  }
]
```

And I want to get something like

```
[
  {
   "name": "Mat",
   "age": "18",
   "subject": "English",
   "mark": 5
  },
  {
   "name": "Mat",
   "age": "18",
   "subject": "Maths",
   "mark": 4
  },
  {
   "name": "Alice",
   "age": 20,
   "city": "New York"
  }
]
```

EDIT: working code is something like

```
rows.forEach(row => {
    let newRow = {}

    _.forOwn(row, (value, key) => {
            value.forEach(item => {
              _.forOwn(item, (value, key) => {
                 newRow[key] = value
               })
            })

           } else {
             newRow[key] = value
           }
      })
  })
```

It doesn't provide first-level properties like `name` and for now it was enough for my reasons but now I need to get all properties except for fields like `studies` in my example.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has working code that isn't shared. Perhaps this should be asked on [codereview.se]

Comment: I think there is no out-of-the-box solutions, you'd have to write your own. What efforts have you made so far?

Comment: @DanielA.White what you mean by `isn't shared`?

Comment: @neoDev "I've got some durty code to do it"...

Comment: @DanielA.White makes sense. thank you :)

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't think that's really fair OP clearly states `It doesn't provide first-level properties like name and for now it was enough for my reasons but now I need to get all properties except for fields like studies in my example.` which means his code is not working as intended. @Dmitry to accomplish this you're going to want to use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a best of luck

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak it was edited after the fact

Comment: I feel like people should be given a bit more than 10 minutes and maybe some helpful suggestions on improving before they are turned down like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern syntax will let you do it like this:

```js
var d = [{"name":"Mat","age":"18","studies":[{"subject":"English","mark":5},{"subject":"Maths","mark":4}]},{"name":"Alice","age":20,"city":"New York"}];

var r = d.reduce((a, {studies, ...rest}) =>
  [...a, ...(studies || [{}]).map(s => ({...s, ...rest}))]
, []); 

console.log(r);
```

Browser support is limited, so use a transpiler if needed.

---

This uses the new *rest syntax* for object literals in the second parameter to the `.reduce()` callback. So basically, `studies` array is put into its own variable and `rest` will be an object with all the remaining properties.

Then we use *spread syntax* for array literals to put the members of the current accumulator array as well as a mapping of the new objects from `studies` into the callback result.

Within the `.map()` callback, we use object literal *spread syntax* to assign the properties of the `rest` object from the `.reduce()` callback, as well as the properties of the current "study" object to a new object literal, which is returned.

If there were no `studies`, we substitute a blank array with an empty object so that it at least gets the `rest` properties.

---

If the key to flatten is dynamic, you can still do it, though it's a little longer.

```js
var d = [{"name":"Mat","age":"18","studies":[{"subject":"English","mark":5},{"subject":"Maths","mark":4}]},{"name":"Alice","age":20,"city":"New York"}];

function flatten(key, data) {
  return data.reduce((a, user) => {
    const arr = user[key];
    delete user[key];
    return [...a, ...(arr || [{}]).map(s => ({...s, ...user}))]
  }, []);
}

console.log(flatten("studies", d));
```

If the destructuring syntax allowed the square bracket expression evaluation like this `{[key], ...user}`, that would clean it up, but right now they don't

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm afraid I'll spend a couple of years trying to understand how it works but it works))

Comment: @Dmitry: I added some explanation to give you a start. :)

Comment: Thanks again! It's far enough I've wanted to get but just wonder if it's be possible to be done recursively and most important **without** binding to `studies` key.

Comment: @Dmitry: It can definitely be done recursively, but I'm not sure what you mean about binding to the `studies` key.

Comment: `(a, {studies, ...rest}` as I can see that `studies` is important there. It wouldn't work with `classes` for example.

Comment: @Dmitry: If you mean you'd like to  supply the key to flatten dynamically, the syntax would change a little, but it can be done.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to pack it into a function and set key dinamically.

Comment: @Dmitry: I added a solution for that. It mutates the original object by removing the property to be flattened. If you don't want that, then first create a new object. `user = {...user}`

Comment: Thanks a lot!)) You'r saviour of my time!

Comment: @Dmitry: Glad it helped.